# How come properties of a SpeechRecognitionAlternative object are not its own?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition, webspeech-api, hasownproperty

Below is a simple demo of how I am using the [Web Speech API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/webspeechapi.html#dfn-transcript) for speech recognition. If you run the demo yourself, just say something after you give mic permissions and watch the console:

```js
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.onresult = function(event) {

 // get SpeechRecognitionResultList object
 var resultList = event.results;

 // get first SpeechRecognitionResult object
 var firstResult = resultList[0];

 // get this result's first SpeechRecognitionAlternative object
 var firstAlternative = firstResult[0];
 
 // this is the puzzling part
 console.log(firstAlternative);
 console.log(firstAlternative.hasOwnProperty('transcript'));
};
recognition.start();
```

In Chrome at least (only webkitty browsers work), I get these two outputs in the console (an object and boolean as expected):

```
{
  "transcript": "hello",
  "confidence": 0.9483599662780762
}
false
```

But I expect to see `true` and not `false` because I would think that `transcript` and `confidence` would pass a `hasOwnProperty` check. Why don't they?

See [SpeechRecognitionAlternative on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognitionAlternative)

Comment: Just filed a [Chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752261).